Visual Bug in Texture Rendering on Car Bumper
I've encountered an issue with my texture while rendering, the lower bumper of the car. During rendering, a visual glitch appears where the texture seems to be composed of small triangles.
Additionally, when I inspect the material preview, I notice that the element has a different color, even though the bumper definitely has the same material.

Why this is happening?

Hard to say from given info ... for now Apply Scale and check Normal direction ...

As mentioned before, check if the scale is applied or if there are normals inverted... or maybe there is some duplicate geometry?

Thanks for the tips. I've already applied the scale and checked the facing direction of the normals, but the problem still remains. I would like to share my model, so here is the link to it. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvXApMXichr2hYdSNaLyFAsKQlk3gA?e=S7fkAe
